# Add OS National Grid names/codes to grid in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I am looking to recreate the full Ordnance Survey National Grid (as shown here https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid.svg) in R.

I can create the grid for the 4 levels without any issues (the 1km version takes about 20 minutes for me with 36GB of RAM):

```
library(sf)

OS_National_Grid_BBox <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -1000000, xmax = 1500000, ymax = 2000000, ymin = -500000), crs = st_crs(27700))

OS_National_Grid_500km <- st_make_grid(st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox), square = T, cellsize = c(500000, 500000)) %>% st_sf()
OS_National_Grid_100km <- st_make_grid(st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox), square = T, cellsize = c(100000, 100000)) %>% st_sf()
OS_National_Grid_10km <- st_make_grid(st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox), square = T, cellsize = c(10000, 10000)) %>% st_sf()
OS_National_Grid_1km <- st_make_grid(st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox), square = T, cellsize = c(1000, 1000)) %>% st_sf()
```

However, how can I name all the 500km, 100km, 10km and 1km cells to reflect the naming/coding convention shown in the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess not too many folks want to tie up their computer for 20 minutes to generate the 6,125,000 polygons en route to testing their answer. As it happens, I had to upgrade my Windows-based cloud server to 32GB just to create the 1km squares...

Unfortunately when you create your grid squares, they are ordered bottom-to-top, left-to-right, whereas the labels are ordered *top-to-bottom*, left-to-right. This makes the labeling a little trickier. For the 500km boxes, we would expect to be able to label them with `LETTERS[-9]`, but because of the ordering we need to label them with `LETTERS[-9][rep(4:0 * 5, each = 5) + 1:5]`.

We can create our named grids by binding together a data frame with the grid names to your grid object, like this:

```r
gridref500 <- LETTERS[-9][rep(4:0 * 5, each = 5) + 1:5]

OS_National_Grid_500km <- st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox)                    %>%
                          st_make_grid(square = TRUE, cellsize = c(5e5, 5e5)) %>% 
                          cbind(data.frame(Grid_Ref = gridref500))            %>%
                          st_sf()
```

Now we can plot to ensure we have the correct labels:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(OS_National_Grid_500km) + 
  geom_sf(fill = "white")      + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = Grid_Ref), size = 5)
```

[image]

The second level is tougher, since we need to repeat the rows and columns within each of the squares. This requires a bit of modular maths to get the indexing right:

```r
gridref100 <- rep(gridref500, each = 5) %>%
              split(0:124 %/% 25)       %>%
              lapply(rep, 5)            %>%
              do.call(c, .)             %>%
              paste0(split(gridref500, 0:24 %/% 5) %>%
                     lapply(rep, 5)                %>%
                     do.call(c, .)                 %>%
                     rep(5))

OS_National_Grid_100km <- st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox)                    %>%
                          st_make_grid(square = TRUE, cellsize = c(1e5, 1e5)) %>% 
                          cbind(data.frame(Grid_Ref = gridref100))            %>%
                          st_sf()
```

But we can see this is also effective:

```
ggplot(OS_National_Grid_100km) + 
  geom_sf(fill = "white")      + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = Grid_Ref), size = 3)
```

[image]

Again, the next layer becomes more complex because of the repetitions, modular maths and subsetting, but can be achieved like this:

```
gridref10  <- rep(gridref100, each = 10) %>%
              split(0:6249 %/% 250)      %>%
              lapply(rep, 10)            %>%
              do.call(c, .)              %>%
              paste0(as.character(rep(0:9, 6250))       %>%
                     paste0(rep(rep(0:9, each = 250), 25)))

OS_National_Grid_10km <- st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox)                    %>%
                         st_make_grid(square = TRUE, cellsize = c(1e4, 1e4)) %>% 
                         cbind(data.frame(Grid_Ref = gridref10))             %>%
                         st_sf()
```

Obviously, I can't plot the entire grid now because it would be far too small to see individual squares (let alone their labels), so I will just pull out `TQ` to ensure the numbering is correct:

```
TQ <- OS_National_Grid_10km[substr(OS_National_Grid_10km$Grid_Ref, 1, 2) == "TQ",]

ggplot(TQ)                + 
  geom_sf(fill = "white") + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = Grid_Ref))
```

[image]

The finest squares would be possible to label too in a similar way to the 10km boxes, with the added complication that after labeling you need to swap the fourth and fifth digits:

```
gridref1  <- rep(gridref10, each = 10)   %>%
  split(0:624999 %/% 2500)    %>%
  lapply(rep, 10)             %>%
  do.call(c, .)               %>%
  paste0(as.character(rep(0:9, 625000))      %>%
           paste0(rep(rep(0:9, each = 2500), 250)))

swapchar               <- substr(gridref1, 4, 4)
substr(gridref1, 4, 4) <- substr(gridref1, 5, 5)
substr(gridref1, 5, 5) <- swapchar

OS_National_Grid_1km  <- st_as_sfc(OS_National_Grid_BBox)                    %>%
  st_make_grid(square = TRUE, cellsize = c(1e3, 1e3)) %>% 
  cbind(data.frame(Grid_Ref = gridref1))              %>%
  st_sf()
```

Again, we need to pick out a small subset to show this works:

```
ss <- with(OS_National_Grid_1km, 
           which(paste0(substr(Grid_Ref, 1, 3), substr(Grid_Ref, 5, 5)) == "TQ28"))

TQ28 <- OS_National_Grid_1km[ss,]

ggplot(TQ28) + 
  geom_sf(fill = "white") + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = Grid_Ref))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works great except for the 1km labels. Taking the TQ28 cell example, none of the 1km labels are generated. If I understand what the code does, it generates the labels in the bottom left corner for the entire grid, goes across the row, moves up to the next row and goes left to right and so on? If so, you would except entry 1501501 in gridref1 to be TQ2080, 1501502 to be TQ2181 etc(if I've got my maths right). There are other oddities where the label VV9000 is repeated 100 times, trying to decipher your code I assume this is meant to be the base that the 1km cells in VV90 are named?

Comment: Also. Should substr be either substr (gridref1, 4,4) or substr(gridref1, 5,5) so they have both start and finish defined?

Comment: @Chris you are right about the `substr`, which I have changed. It sounds as though I have got the 1km grid wrong. I'll try to think of a way to debug it without having to generate the actual grid (or rent a bigger server)

Comment: @Chris I think I've fixed it. `split(0:62499 %/% 2500)` should have been `split(0:62499 %/% 250)`

Comment: I've tried that and it seems to create all the unique labels, just in the wrong places. Going from the bottom left again. The labels for the 1km cells in VV and VW are fine. Half of the labels for VX are correct, but VX5000 is directly above the VV cell (VV0009). So it does the first 250km across and the first 10km up fine.

Comment: So I think this fixes it: split(0:624999 %/% 2500)

Comment: I think you could be right there @Chris. Sorry I couldn't debug this myself.

Comment: @Chris can you let me know whether this worked? If so, I can update the answer with your fix.

Comment: It appears to have worked as expected. I will double check the output in the next day, but assume it's all good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Chris I had to rent a cloud server with 32 GB memory to confirm this works - I have plotted the final grid to demonstrate it!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to associate points with grid codes (per your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239578/creating-1m-5m-10m-50m-100m-and-500m-grids-with-os-national-grid-codes-in-r)), you could also compute the codes on the fly.

Here is a function that does that

```
getG <- function(pnt) {
    numcodes <- function(x, cell) {
        rc <- rowColFromCell(x, cell)
        c(rc[2]-1, 10-rc[1])
    }
    r <- rast(ext=c(-1000000, 1500000, -500000, 2000000), crs="EPSG:27700", res=500000)
    LTS <- LETTERS[-9]

    # first level
    xy <- rbind(pnt)
    c1 <- cellFromXY(r, xy)

    # second level
    r <- disagg(r[c1, drop=FALSE], 5)
    c2 <- cellFromXY(r, xy)

    # third level
    r <- disagg(r[c2, drop=FALSE], 10)
    cxy <- cellFromXY(r, xy)
    cr3 <- numcodes(r, cxy)

    # fourth level (no need for disagg)
    ext(r) <- ext(r[cxy, drop=FALSE])
    cxy <- cellFromXY(r, xy)
    cr4 <- numcodes(r, cxy)

    paste0(LTS[c1], LTS[c2], cr3[1], cr4[1], cr3[2], cr4[2], collapse="")
}
```

Call the function

```
library(terra)
pnts <- rbind(cbind(93555, 256188), 
              cbind(210637, 349798),
              cbind(696457,481704))

getG(pnts[1,])
#[1] "SL9356"

apply(pnts, 1, getG)
#[1] "SL9356" "SH1049" "TB9681"
```

---

This functionality is now also available in geosphere v1.5-19.

```
library(geosphere)
pnts <- rbind(cbind(93555, 256188), 
      cbind(210637, 349798),
      cbind(696457,481704))

OSGB(pnts, "1km")
#[1] "SL9356" "SH1049" "TB9681"
```

geosphere v1.5-19 is currently the development version. You can install it with

```
install.packages('geosphere', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the same logic can be applied to assign cells below 1km?

Comment: That is my thinking, I have cleaned up the function a bit to make that easier to do